# Typescript serializing generic

Tags: typescript, generics, serialization

I have the following base class:

```
export default class BaseModel{
    Id:string;
    CreatedDate:Date;
}
```

With following child class:

```
export default class ProfileModel extends BaseModel{
    UserName:string;
    Email:string;
    Password:string;
    FirstName:string;
    LastName:string;
    Vendor:Boolean;
    Authenticated:Boolean;
    constructor(aUserName, anEmail, aPassword, aFirstName, aLastName, 
aVendor, isAuthenticated){
    super();
    this.UserName = aUserName;
    this.Email = anEmail;
    this.Password = aPassword;
    this.FirstName = aFirstName;
    this.LastName = aLastName;
    this.Vendor = aVendor;
    this.Authenticated = isAuthenticated;
    }
    public static NewNonVendor(aUserName, anEmail, aPassword, aFirstName, 
aLastName):ProfileModel{
        return new ProfileModel(aUserName, anEmail, aPassword, aFirstName, 
    aLastName, null, false);
    }
}
```

I would like to move the fromJSON method to base class to handle serialization for all child classes. I want to basically do the following but having trouble coming up with the correct syntax:

```
export default class BaseModel<T>{
    Id:string;
    CreatedDate:Date;
    static fromJSON(d: Object): T {
        return Object.assign(new T(), d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type the T generic as `T extends BaseModel`, you can type the `this` for the static method as `this: new () => T`:

```
class BaseModel {
  Id: string;
  CreatedDate: Date;
  static fromJSON<T extends BaseModel>(this: new () => T, d: Object): T {
    return Object.assign(new this(), d);
  }
  constructor(Id: string, CreatedDate: Date) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.CreatedDate = CreatedDate;
  }
}
```

Comment: @CeertainPerformance Yes this appears to work. Was there a reason you added the constructor?

Comment: Only so that the TypeScript would compile properly on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) without errors (use your original constructor implementation, of course - it isn't in the question, so it was throwing a TS error)

Comment: so now when trying to call fromJSON using following: let test = ProfileModel.fromJSON(json as Object); I get following error: The 'this' context of type 'typeof ProfileModel' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'new () => ProfileModel'.

Comment: It looks to compile without errors here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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

Comment: Also note that JSON is a way of representing an object in a *string*. If what you have is an *object*, it's not a JSON - maybe call it `fromPlainObject` instead of `fromJSON`? Or pass in the JSON and use `JSON.parse` on it inside the method?

Comment: Ok so removing parameters from constructor worked. So how would this work with parameters in constructor?

Comment: I don't see your constructor in the question - the right method to use will depend on its implementation. You might just need `Object.assign(Object.create(this.prototype), d)`. That'd be the ideal method. If the arguments are dynamic for subclasses, I don't think there's a good elegant way to do it, because you'd need to pass in the appropriate arguments in order to call the `new this` properly - but you only know them via the object passed in, not from arguments, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Really all i want is to have deserialization occur at base level. I can just have all the child classes implement their own if that is the best way to do it. Not the end of the world.

Comment: Then that's what you'd do: `static fromJSON<T extends BaseModel>(this: new () => T, d: Object): T {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(this.prototype), d);
  }`